# Solving a system of ODEs with the Runge-Kutta method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs using a fourth-order Runge-Kutta method. I have to recreate certain results to obtain my degree. But I'm a beginner at *Mathematica* programming and with the Runge-Kutta method as well.

```
{A = 0.30, B = 1, C = 40, D = 1, E = 0.75, F = 0.11,
 r = 2.5, a = 2, e = 0.475, g = 2, d = 0.03, n = 0.01, p = -0.00005}

x'[t]/x[t] = (A + B x[t] - C x[t]^2 - F)/(D + E^(r y[t]));   
y'[t]/y[t] = g (((a s[t] x[t] k[t])/m[t]) - e) (1 - y[t]); 
m'[t]/m[t] = n;
k'[t]/k[t] = x[t] - d;
s'[t]/s[t] = -p;
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help. For over a month now, I've tried to solve this system myself but have only gotten bad results. This model is supposed to fluctuate around the equilibrium point, but in the code I have so far, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Please don't use single capital letters as variables: both `C` and `E` are protected system symbols, and no value should be assigned to them. Also note that multiplication requires at least a space, thus `Cx` is a symbol while `C x` is `C` times `x`

Comment: Runge-Kutta 4 is described in the documentation as a example [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a functional approach. The following will give you one step of the Runge-Kutta formula:

```
RungeKutta[func_List, yinit_List, y_List, step_] := 
 Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4},
  k1 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, yinit}]];
  k2 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k1/2 + yinit}]];
  k3 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k2/2 + yinit}]];
  k4 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k3 + yinit}]];
  yinit + Total[{k1, 2 k2, 2 k3, k4}]/6]
```

Here, `func` is a list of functions, `yinit` a list of initial values, `y` a list of function variables (in your case that will be `{x, y, m, k, s}`, and `step` is the step size of the numerical simulation.
You can then use something like `NestList` to iterate it many times like this:

```
NestList[RungeKutta[func, #, y, step] &, N[yinit], Round[t/step]]
```

Here, `t` is the maximum value of your independent variable. 
You can also include conditionals to check that the lists are of equal length.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have achieved my simulation. With the huge help of your answer!

Comment: @IsaiasCordova, glad I could help.

Comment: Er… I think it's better to mention that the `y` for `RungeKutta[]` usually include `t` for more general cases. (And the counterpart of `t` is `1` in `yinit`.)

Comment: @IsaiasCordova Can you please post the complete answer here?

Comment: @xzczd, yes, that version as written in this answer is intended for autonomous equations; Maeder's book implemented it this way initially, but then also gave a version for non-autonomous DEs.

Answer (score 19):

andre has linked you to the [method plug-in framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html) in the comments, but there is a more direct way to implement classical Runge-Kutta, just by [supplying its Butcher tableau to `"ExplicitRungeKutta"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#205676559). Here's an adaptation from the docs:

```
ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, prec_] := With[{amat = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}},
           bvec = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6}, cvec = {1/2, 1/2, 1}}, N[{amat, bvec, cvec}, prec]]

{xf, yf} = {x, y} /. First @ 
           NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0},
                   {x, y}, {t, 0, 6}, 
                   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4,
                              "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients},
                   StartingStepSize -> 1/2];
```

To obtain the values computed by RK, you can then do this:

```
xl = MapThread[Append, {xf["Grid"], xf["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
   {{0., 1.}, {0.5, 0.877604}, {1., 0.540588}, {1.5, 0.0714256}, {2., -0.415108},
    {2.5, -0.800012}, {3., -0.989166}, {3.5, -0.936349}, {4., -0.65453}, {4.5, -0.212684},
    {5., 0.281088}, {5.5, 0.706007}, {6., 0.95816}}

yl = MapThread[Append, {yf["Grid"], yf["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
   {{0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.479167}, {1., 0.841037}, {1.5, 0.99713}, {2., 0.90931},
    {2.5, 0.599108}, {3., 0.142441}, {3.5, -0.348969}, {4., -0.754924}, {4.5, -0.976153},
    {5., -0.958587}, {5.5, -0.706572}, {6., -0.281796}}
```

Plot them:

```
ListLinePlot[{xl, yl}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image: plot of approximate solution from RK]

Comment: Hey, I have a question. why do they call the vector on the inner part of the butchear tableau amac and not avec? I don't quite see why they call it that. Not a big issue, but just conufsed by it. It is because it's a matrix and not a vector? and if so, why doesn't it have for example, as the entries, {{1/2,0,0},{0,1/2,0},{0,0,1}}? Is it because we add the factors in as necessary, so exclude and 0s after the last entry for that step of the algorithm?

Comment: @Shinaolord, in fact, the coefficient matrix is a *strictly* lower triangular matrix, so the actual complete matrix is something like `{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}`. For *explicit* RK methods, by convention, the upper triangular entries are omitted; for *implicit* RK, methods, however, the full matrix will usually be shown in the Butcher tableau.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I'd like to emphasize that, if you just want to solve an initial value problem (IVP) of ordinary differential equation (ODE) or ODE system, **please use `NDSolve`**. Forget about the classical Runge-Kutta (classical RK, RK4), it's mainly for pedagogical purposes nowadays, and not comparable to the default method of `NDSolve` at all. If default method of `NDSolve` fails to solve your IVP, RK4 won't save your day, either. Actually I've never seen a knotty problem solved by switching from default `NDSolve` method to RK4 since I began using *Mathematica* 10 years ago.

If you need RK4 for certain special reason (e.g. to exactly reproduce numeric result obtained with RK4 in literature, to ensure the result can be easily reproduced by others, etc.), setting proper options for `NDSolve` is the way to go. Please refer to [J.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23583/1871) for more info. Here I'll provide a general-purposed package for setting up explicit Runge-Kutta method with no adaptive step control, which is implemented without the help of `NDSolve`, just for fun:

```
BeginPackage["primaryRK`"];
rkstepgenerator; rhsfuncgenerator; rk4stepfunc;
Begin["`private`"];

rule = {semi -> CompoundExpression, set -> Set, 
        module -> Module, compile -> Compile};
SetAttributes[semi, Flat];
f[{}, _] := {};

rkstepgenerator[a_, b_, c_] := (s = Length@b;
  k = ToExpression["k" <> ToString@#] & /@ Range@s;
  Function @@ {f, 
     compile[{t, {y, _Real, 1}, dt}, 
      module[k, semi[
        semi @@ Thread@
          set[k, Prepend[Thread@f[t + c dt, y + dt k . PadRight[#, s] & /@ a], 
            f[t, y]]],
        y + dt b . k]]]} /. rule)

a = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}};
b = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6};
c = {1/2, 1/2, 1};

rk4stepfunc = rkstepgenerator[a, b, c];

rhsfuncgenerator[t_, ylst_][expr_] := 
 Function @@ {{t, yvec}, module[ylst, semi[ylst~set~yvec, expr]]} /. rule

End[];
EndPackage[]
```

Since RK4 is so frequently requested, a function `rk4stepfunc` is included in the package. Let me use the IVP

\begin{aligned}x'(t)&=-y(t)\\
y'(t)&=x(t)+\sin(3t)\\
x(0)&=1\\
y(0)&=0\end{aligned}

to illustrate its possible usage:

```
heads = {x, y}; 
vars = heads[t] // Through;
eqs = {x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t] + Sin[3 t]};
iclst = {1, 0};
domain = {t0, tend} = {0, 6};

(* Analytic solution for comparison: *)
ref = Plot[
        vars /. DSolve[{eqs, vars == iclst /. t -> t0}, vars, t] // 
        Evaluate, {t, t0, tend}];

expr = 
  Solve[eqs, D[vars, t]][[1, All, -1]] /. 
    (h : Alternatives @@ heads)[t] :> h
(* {-y, x + Sin[3 t]} *)

Internal`$ContextMarks = False; (* Default value is Automatic *)

rhsfunc = rhsfuncgenerator[t, heads]@expr
(* Function[{t, yvec}, Module[{x, y}, {x, y} = yvec; {-y, x + Sin[3 t]}]] *)

step = rk4stepfunc@rhsfunc;

dt = 1/30;
tlst = Range[t0, tend, dt];

sollst = 
   FoldList[step[#2[[1]], #, #2[[2]]] &, iclst, 
    Transpose@{Most@tlst, Differences@tlst}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0013601, Null} *)

ListPlot[Thread /@ Thread@{tlst, sollst} // Transpose]~Show~ref
```

[image]

You can of course use the package to set up other explicit Runge-Kutta method with no error estimation e.g. explicit Euler. Just for fun, let me show another possible usage of the package:

```
eulerstepfunc = rkstepgenerator[{{}}, {1}, {}]
(* Function[f, 
            Compile[{t, {y, _Real, 1}, dt}, 
                    Module[{k1}, k1 = f[t, y]; dt k1 + y]]] *)

step = eulerstepfunc@rhsfunc;
dt = 1/50;
ti = t0 - dt;
sollst = NestList[
        step[ti = ti + dt, #, dt] &, iclst, #2 - # & @@ domain/dt // 
     Round]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0007594, Null} *)
ListPlot[sollst\[Transpose], DataRange -> domain, PlotStyle -> Red]~Show~ref
```

[image]

Heun's method (Once again, I'll show a different usage of the package for fun):

```
heunstepfunc = 
 With[{α = 1}, 
  rkstepgenerator[{{α}}, {1 - 1/(2 α), 1/(2 α)}, {α}]]
(* Function[f, 
 Compile[{t, {y, _Real, 1}, dt}, 
         Module[{k1, k2}, k1 = f[t, y]; 
                          k2 = f[dt + t, dt k1 + y]; 
                          dt (k1/2 + k2/2) + y]]] *)

step = heunstepfunc@rhsfunc;
sollst = With[{dt = 1/20, t0 = N@t0, step = step, iclst = N@iclst}, 
           With[{n = 1 - Subtract @@ domain/dt},
            Compile[{}, Module[{lst = Table[iclst, {n}], ti = t0},
                Do[lst[[i]] = step[ti, lst[[i - 1]], dt];
                   ti = ti + dt, {i, 2, n}];
                lst]]]][]; // AbsoluteTiming

Show[sollst\[Transpose] // 
  ListPlot[#, DataRange -> domain, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &, ref]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice indeed! :)

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing `NDSolve`. There are so many questions here about RK4. It seems many supervisors have zero idea about the capabilities of modern computer algebra systems. It's like teaching driving cars with manual transmission when everyone is already driving Tesla.

Comment: @yarchik "It seems many supervisors have zero idea..." — I've seen the Euler method used fairly often. Like using a hand crank to start your car. :)