# Runge-Kutta-2 on System

Tags: differential-equations, code-review

After spending some time using the Mathematica documentation and this  Mathematica.SE [*answer*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23516/solving-a-system-of-odes-with-the-runge-kutta-method), I implemented the Runge-Kutta-2 routines.

I am hoping someone can validate what I did and tell me that it is correct (especially the Butcher Tableau I used) and the step size $h = 0.1$.

```
  ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, prec_] := 
   With[{amat = {{1/2}}, bvec = {0, 1}, cvec = {1/2}}, 
    N[{amat, bvec, cvec}, prec]]

  {xf, yf} = {x, y} /. 
    First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, 
     y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 6}, 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
    "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}, 
     StartingStepSize -> 1/10];

  xl = MapThread[Append, {xf["Grid"], xf["ValuesOnGrid"]}]

  yl = MapThread[Append, {yf["Grid"], yf["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
```

We can find a closed form solution to this problem as:

```
  s = DSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, t]
```

Lastly, is there an automated way to update and step through each variant of RK-2, RK-3, RK-4, ... without having to manually enter the Butcher values (in other words, I want to step through each variant of RK-n and compare the errors (a table of that would be great))?

There is a hint of this at [*Wolfram's Reference page*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html).

Note: I am embarrassed to say that I did not totally understand `ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients` (other than the coefficients).

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your original code is that the order argument you specified (`4`) is in fact not the same as the order of the midpoint method (`2`). Thus:

```
MidpointCoefficients[2, prec_] := N[{{{1/2}}, {0, 1}, {1/2}}, prec];
```

For comparison purposes, here's the Butcher table for Heun's method:

```
HeunCoefficients[2, prec_] := N[{{{1}}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1}}, prec];
```

We can now pass the Butcher table to `NDSolve[]` like so:

```
{xm, ym} = {x, y} /. 
  First @ NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0},
                  {x, y}, {t, 0, 6}, 
                  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, 
                             "Coefficients" -> MidpointCoefficients}, 
                  StartingStepSize -> 1/10];
```

and check that the results are as expected:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xm["ValuesOnGrid"], ym["ValuesOnGrid"]}], 
             AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: circle arc using the midpoint method]

```
{Norm[xc["ValuesOnGrid"] - Cos[Range[0, 6, 1/10]], ∞], 
 Norm[yc["ValuesOnGrid"] - Sin[Range[0, 6, 1/10]], ∞]}
   {0.00813941, 0.00938408}
```

---

> Lastly, is there an automated way to update and step through each variant of RK-2, RK-3, RK-4, ... without having to manually enter the Butcher values ... ?

In principle, one could certainly use *Mathematica* to solve the underlying algebraic equations satisfied by the coefficients of an $n$-th order Runge-Kutta method. But, as noted in the venerable book of [Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner](http://books.google.com/books?id=113xCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA153), the so-called *order conditions* very quickly become more numerous and complicated as the order is increased, so one often relies on trickery and/or approximations to generate usable higher-order coefficients. So, you could *try*, but you'd find it way easier to stand on the shoulders of giants.