# Help with NDSolve for system of odes

Tags: code-request, code-generation, broken-code

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to solve a system of odes using NDSolve. The code I have written is as follows:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == cos[t] + 4sin[t] - 4[x] - 2[y], y'[t] == -3sin[t] + 
3[x] + [y], x[0] == 0, y[0] == -1},{x[t],y[t]},t]
```

However I am getting an error that says

```
Syntax:"-3sin[t]+3[x]+" cannot be followed by "[y]".
```

I have tried taking the brackets off [y] which results in

```
NDSolve: The function y appears with no arguments.
```

Any help would  be greatly appreciated. Also how would I plot a solution curve for this ODE after getting NDSolve to function?

Comment: what do you mean with `4[x]` and `2[y]`? Are those functions?? Also, the sinus function ist written in Mathematica with capital S, `Sin[x]` is $\sin(x)$. You should first take a look at basic syntax in Mathematica.

Comment: You made the `Sin` sin [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145393/huens-method-for-a-system-of-odes#comment391012_145393)!  Please show some signs of learning instead of asking people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
eqns = {
   x'[t] == Cos[t] + 4 Sin[t] - 4 x[t] - 2 y[t],
   y'[t] == -3 Sin[t] + 3 x[t] + y[t],
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == -1};
```

This system can be solved exactly with [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) without using numeric techniques of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
soln = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t][[1]]

(*  {x -> Function[{t}, E^(-2 t) (-2 + 2 E^t + E^(2 t) Sin[t])], 
 y -> Function[{t}, -E^(-2 t) (-2 + 3 E^t)]}  *)
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equations and initial conditions,

```
And @@ (eqns /. soln // Simplify)

(*  True  *)

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 3 Pi},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{x[t], y[t]}, {0.85, 0.2}]]
```

[image]