# Plot column using some list as x values?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I've got a mathematica notebook that uses RK4 to successively approximate solutions to a vector valued DE. The output is a nested list similar to:

```
solutions := {{a[t0],b[t0],c[t0],d[t0]},{a[t0+dt],b[t0+dt],c[t0+dt],d[t0+dt]},...}
```

The list that I want to use as the x-axis is simply `{t0,t0+dt,t0+2dt,...}`, and I want to plot it against the `a` column of my `solutions` matrix. Perhaps I'm missing it, but I couldn't get `ParametricPlot` to work with these lists.

Here's a link to my notebook: http://pastebin.com/ZK0pUBSz

Sample data:

```
t:={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200}

y:={200.,177.847,162.025,150.607,142.306,136.239,131.788,128.518,126.111,124.341,123.04}
```

Desired output is a plot with y as the dependent variable and t as the independent variable.

---

(edit: Solved! I had previously defined solutions as a matrix without any argument, and when I tried to turn it into something that took an argument, the kernel threw up errors. Solved by running a simple `Remove@solutions`.)

An an extra aside, my end goal is to see the effect of step size on solution resolution. I tried to accomplish this using the following code:

```
Tlist[step_] := 
Transpose[{Range[0, tmax, step], Part[solutions[step], All, 1]}];
ListLinePlot[{TList[.1], Tlist[.5], Tlist[1]}]
```

I'm trying to create a plot with each step size using Tlist, but the evaluation fails with write protection. Maybe this isn't the right way to tackle this problem in Mathematica, and I'm taking too much of a procedural approach. Any guidance on this would be welcome!

Here's the code for `solutions`:

```
RungeKutta[func_List, yinit_List, y_List, step_] := 
 Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4}, 
  k1 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, yinit}]];
  k2 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k1/2 + yinit}]];
  k3 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k2/2 + yinit}]];
  k4 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k3 + yinit}]];
  yinit + Total[{k1, 2 k2, 2 k3, k4}]/6]
solutions[step_] := 
 NestList[RungeKutta[func, #, y, step] &, N[yinit], Round[tmax/step]]
```

RungeKutta code from here: [Solving a system of ODEs with the Runge-Kutta method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23516/solving-a-system-of-odes-with-the-runge-kutta-method/23583#23583)

Comment: Welcome! It would be easier to help you if you included some actual data to plot with, but I suspect `Thread` or `MapThread` or `Transpose` may come in handy here.

Comment: I added a link to the notebook, sorry about that! I'll look at those functions!

Comment: No problem! If you post a small sample (or just bogus data with the same structure) here, you will get more answers. This will be quicker to browse, more convenient and secure for users to access, and permanent (your link may vanish).

Comment: Okay, I'll add some in.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks, bbgodfrey. @YvesKlett, the information you asked for has been included. Although, I'm not exactly sure why the second value is repeated over and over in the yvalues list.

Comment: For your sample data and alsoalso the pastebin code: consider using `Set` (`=`) instead of using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for your sample lists for instance. Not so important in this case but that will avoid unnecessary evaluations of expressions and can tremensously reduce runtime of code

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Lukas. I've added a minor edit to my question about functions in mathematica if you have time to look.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Of course, you first have to properly define your solutions function so that it actualy is a fubction of `step`. But the plotting should be okay as far as i can see. Edit: just realized that you tried to run thr code... You have to define the a function `solutions[step_]` before you use it so that Mathematica knowd what to do

Comment: @Lukas, added the solutions[] code that throws the errors. Maybe I'm doing it differently than I should be.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run the code on a computer right now to help ypu. Using a mobile all the time. You'll have to wait for another one or until the day after tomorrow for me to actually run the code

Comment: @ijustlovemath It would be very nice to give a link to the author of the RungeKutta code. [solving-a-system-of-odes-with-the-runge-kutta-method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23516/solving-a-system-of-odes-with-the-runge-kutta-method/23583#23583) [RunnyKine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine)

Comment: @Lukas, I figured it out. I had to do a `Remove@solutions` before it would allow me to pass it a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `xColumn` is the column of x-values and `yColumn` the y-values. Then - as pointed to by YvesKlett - you could use `ListPlot[Transpose[{xColumn,yColumn}]]`, for instance.

In your case:

```
xColumn=Table[t0+i*dt,{i,0,n}];
yColumn=solutions[[All,1]];
```

Here, `n` clearly has to be adjusted to your code, depending on how long your time interval is. Then use for instance the `ListPlot` command from above with option `Joined->True` or use `ListLinePlot` instead.

Comment: I see. So here, we transpose the nested list to make it an appropriate list for listplot? Thanks so much for the clarification

Comment: Well, since you want to plot only the first column of your solution matrix you first extract it via `solutions[[All,1]]`. Then you essentially form the x-y tuples using `Transpose` so that it is in  the required form for the plot commands. Glad I could help

Comment: Would it be possible to make that `Transpose` a function of step size, for plotting multiple plots over varying step sizes?