# Runge-Kutta methods in Mathematica for systems of first order Differential Equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

[image]

The algorithm isn't given any output, the graph is unidentifiable.
The systems of Differential Equations considered:

$$
     x'[t]=-x[t]+y[t]\\
    y'[t]=-x[t]-y[t]\\
x[0]=0, y[0]=4, h=0.1$$

Please how do I represent k1, l1, k2, l2, k3, l3, k4, l4, y(n+1), and x(n+1) for the simulation to run?

Here is the code:

```
    DSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], y'[t] == -x[t] - y[t], 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 4}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
    {{x[t] -> 4 E^-t Sin[t], y[t] -> 4 E^-t Cos[t]}}

    In[2]:= ti = 0;
   tf = 10 ;
   m = 100;
   Δt = (tf - ti)/m;
   T = Range[ti, tf, Δt] // N;
   X = ConstantArray[0., m + 1];
   Y = ConstantArray[0., m + 1];

   In[1]:= X[[1]] = 0.;
   Y[[1]] = 4.;
   Do[
    k1 = Δt ( Y[[n]] - X[[n]]);
    l1 = -Δt (X[[n]] + Y[[n]]);
    k2 = Δt ( (Y[[n]] + l1/2) - (X[[n]] + k1/2));
    l2 = -Δt ( (X[[n]] + k1/2) + (Y[[n]] + l1/2));
    k3 = Δt ( (Y[[n]] + k2/2) - (X[[n]] + l2/2));
    l3 = -Δt ( (X[[n]] + k2/2) + (Y[[n]] + l2/2));
    k4 = Δt ( (Y[[n]] + k3) - (X[[n]] + l3));
    l4 = -Δt ( (X[[n]] + k3) + (Y[[n]] + l3));
    X[[n + 1]] = Y[[n]] - X[[n]] + 1/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4);
    Y[[n + 1]] = -X[[n]] - Y[[n]] + 1/6 (l1 + 2 l2 + 2 l3 + l4),{n, 1, m}]
```

I am having a hard time using this algorithm to compute for the systems of ODE.
The first algorithm seems to be much.
I would be glad if anyone can help out

```
rk4Step[{f_, t_, y_, stepSize_}] :=
 Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4, h = N[stepSize]},
  k1 = h f[N[t], y];
  k2 = h f[t + h/2, y + 1/2 k1];
  k3 = h f[t + h/2, y + 1/2 k2];
  k4 = h f[t + h, y + k3];
  {f, t + h, y + 1/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4), h}]

RK4[f_, t0_, y0_, tEnd_, n_] := 
 Module[{h = N[(tEnd - t0)/n]}, 
 Most /@ Rest /@ NestList[rk4Step, {f, t0, y0, h}, n]]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `Do[]` has no output. What happens if you execute `X` or `Y`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23516/solving-a-system-of-odes-with-the-runge-kutta-method

Comment: You may have a typo in your expression for `k2`.  The expression refers to a variable `K1`.  Maybe that should be lowercase `k1`.

Comment: @LouisB I changed, it's the same.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Irrespective of that, it should give output. I tried it when simulating for Euler's method, and it gave output.

Comment: @MichaelE2 , thanks for making the first comment

Comment: "Irrespective of that, it should give output." No, it (the `Do[]` command) shouldn't. Why do you think it should? That you got output with a **different code** (Euler's method) does not mean **this code** would produce output; it just means you used a command that produced output. In changing the code to RK4, you (inadvertently) got rid of the output command. From your code above, I do get output from `ListLinePlot[Transpose@{X, Y}]`.

Comment: [A related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23516).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for bringing it to my notice, I just observed that I was supposed to have removed the back spacing immediately after the Do[k1... ] command. It was empty because of the spacing there.